# Comment button problem on SO

Tags: support, comments

The "Add Comment" button on SO has started appearing to the right of the comment text input box. This makes it get covered up by the text for adverts et al. Can we have it appearing under the comment input, please.

[http://kwout.com/cutout/8/xc/9c/36t_bor.jpg http://kwout.com/cutout/8/xc/9c/36t_bor.jpg](http://kwout.com/cutout/8/xc/9c/36t_bor.jpg)

John's suggestion of using non-text zoom has improved things. However, I still get this strange display when I edit a comment:

[http://kwout.com/cutout/6/qe/zq/s2u_bor.jpg http://kwout.com/cutout/6/qe/zq/s2u_bor.jpg](http://kwout.com/cutout/6/qe/zq/s2u_bor.jpg)

Comment: I think a screenshot with freehand circles is needed. Otherwise you're going to hear the programmer's lament - "It works for me!"

Comment: The lack of freehand circles offends my eyes!

Comment: Not reproducible. Hit CTRL+F5. If it still occurs: Browser, version, OS?

Comment: Firefox 3.5.6, Win2K SP4.

Comment: Win2K? Ouch! I had several issues on my old laptop with Win2K and (older) Firefox versions, which weren't reproducible with WinXP. The OS could be the culprit here (or the incompatibility of FF with this OS).

Comment: Well, I've been using SO for 10 months now on the same machine & OS and this problem seems to have started today. I suspect there has been a code change. And Win2K is certainly much more reliable & performant  than some of the recent bloatware issuing from Redmond.

Comment: Yes, there was a change. You can edit comments now (for the first 5 minutes). That's why I suggested CTRL+F5. Maybe you should consider clearing your cache, too. Have you tried Safe mode?

Comment: Neither Ctrl-F5 nor clearing the cache have any effect.

Comment: Safe Mode neither? Extensions like Firebug can cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: No, safe mode makes no difference. and I don't use too many addons - just AdBlock, NoScript and a status bar enhancement.

Comment: Does this appear always, or only with some special questions?

Comment: Always, and not just on SO, but om Meta too.

Comment: Do you see the *edit* link somewhere to edit your comment? It should be next to the time stamp ("1 min ago edit")

Comment: Yep, I get that. If I hit it though I end up with a rather strange display with two edit inputs and two buttons.The top one is labelled "Save Your Edit" and the bottom one, who's edit contains no text, has a button labelled "Add Comment"

Comment: Strange? Shoot it!

Comment: Cou;ld someone post a shot of what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Sure. See my answer.

Comment: I see two edit textboxes as well (just like in Neil's second screenshot): OSX 10.6.2, Firefox 3.5.6.

Comment: I've the same problem. The button to add a comment is being overlapped over `Related` column on the right. Ubuntu 9.10 FF 3.5.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strange display is normal. It just shows the comment edit box and the box to enter a complete new comment.

It looks different from my previous shot, because your comment is the last one, just above the "add comment" box. In my shot it was a comment between two other comments.

Comment: Rather strange GUI design, IMHO - but thanks v. much for your help.

Comment: You're always welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I have this strange problem, also.  Recommendation: put the button and links below the box.  It will work every time.  Sometimes life is just easier if you agree with the Muses.  I've wasted an hour too much on this problem.

See question [39570](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39570/why-is-the-comments-box-obscured-by-right-hand-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

I have on many occasions found that this sort of error was because of PeerBlock, ProtoWall, or an ad-blocker blocking an external CSS or JS file.

Disable AdBlock, NoScript, etc. Those very addons (ie ad blockers) are exactly the ones that cause this sort of behavior on web pages. Turn off all extensions as well as external security things like IP blockers, etc. and see if it works. Then you can go through the process of figuring out which blocking app is the one that is causing it and which IP/site/file/etc. is being blocked, then create an exception for it.

Comment: As  I said in my comment, I get the same problem in safe mode, where those addons are not loaded.

Comment: I thought you meant Windows safe mode (I haven’t used FireFox in a long time).

Anyway, it could still have been an external ad/ip blocker or something blocking a CSS or JS file.

Answer (score 0):

[alt text http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/4315/commentedit.png](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/4315/commentedit.png)

Comment: OK, that is more or less what I am getting (I still get the extra edit below it however). But I use a fairly large font size (I'm getting old) and this is pushing the button into the right-hand text. This seems simply like poor design - if the button was positioned UNDER the edit, there woould be less of a problem. This is on a 17 inch 1280 x 1024 screen, BTW, so it's not like I'm trying to scrunch things into a tiny display.

Comment: You are using large font size? Aaahhh! Why didn't you mention that from the beginning? Use the zoom function of the browser instead. It scales better than just increasing your font.

Comment: Zoom is what I do use - same problem.

Comment: There is a difference between "font only zoom" and "zoom". Always zoom the whole page, not only the fonts. "View"->"Zoom"->"Zoom Text only" must _not_ be checked!

Comment: That does improve things - thanks! I still get the strange "two edits" behaviour - will try and post a shot of that, to prove I'm not hallicinating.