# "Add comment" button over the Related links (and therefore unusable)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, design, firefox

The "Add comment" button is now in the middle of the (clickable) links of the Related section, which often makes it unusable.

[image: The "Add comment" button at the wrong place.]

I didn't use SO for one or two months so I don't know exactly how it appeared.

Firefox 3.0.6 on Debian.

It seems similar to [Comment button problem on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33954/comment-button-problem-on-so) which has an accepted answer which seems irrelevant to me (this is certainly **not** a normal display).

Comment: Have nothing to say about your css issue. But **why** in the world are you using such an old version of Firefox?

Comment: You use the wrong kind of zoom. Read the comments of my second answer to the question you link to.

Comment: It is the version of Firefox shipped with Debian stable. Is SO reserved to the people who have nothing else to do than upgrading their browser every month?

Comment: Of course not, but there have been quite a few security issues fixed since 3.0.6 came out. I was just curious, no need to get defensive about it.

Comment: In theory, the Debian package backports the security fixes, so, even if the version number does not change, it may be safe.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Firefox 3.6.8 on Mac.  I have to open up a different browser if I want to make comments.  If I can be of assistance in resolving this issue, please contact me.

Comment: It happens for me with Chrome.  It's really annoying because if you forget and click the button and hit the link instead it throws away your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Those fonts are.. curious.

I think you have overridden default fonts -- have you?

Can you try to repro in another browser (I recommend Chrome on Linux), or try with Firefox in a default configuration?

Comment: No, standard fonts, as shipped with the Debian package configuration.

Comment: This bug does not occur with Google Chrome (just downloaded). Since other bugs occur with Chrome, I will open separated reports (they may be Chrome's fault).

Comment: Indeed, on another Debian machine, absolutely identical, but with sansserif fonts, the bug does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between "font only zoom" and "zoom". Always zoom the whole page, not only the fonts. "View"->"Zoom"->"Zoom Text only" must not be checked!

[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8391/zoomq.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/8391/zoomq.png)

Comment: No, "Zoom text only" was not checked. I tried it, just to see, but no change.