# Move "Add Comment" button to below comment box, otherwise it can be covered by ad

Tags: feature-request, design, android

I've seen the button in the links area ([two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33954/comment-button-problem-on-so) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35051/add-comment-button-over-the-related-links-and-therefore-unusable)) due to text overflow, but that's nothing compared to this:

[image]

On my phone browser, the button is usually **completely** covered by ad.

I think a very simple but effective solution is to put the button under the comment box, just like the answer button.

Answer (score 1):

Get a life.

(Or, stop using SE on your phone.)

It's acceptable but really, really, [hard to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11652/how-addicted-to-stack-overflow-are-you/65308#65308).

Answer (score 0):

Use ad blocking software.

It's acceptable but not satisfactory, and there doesn't seem to be such a thing for my HTC Incredible.

Answer (score 0):

Press Enter.

I'll actually be doing this, since getting out of input mode and looking for a button to click is way harder, no matter where the button is located.

I still think it's more consistent to put the button below, though.

(I wonder if there's a badge for too many self answers.)